# Use RealityKit ARView on macOS

Tags: macos, scenekit, virtual-reality, realitykit

I'm trying to use an `ARView` in a macOS-only project. I can load a scene (tested with a Reality file from Reality Composer), and it renders fine.

But how do I control the camera with the mouse?

An example of this is Reality Composer, Reality Converter, and previewing a Reality file in Xcode where you can drag anywhere on the view and the camera pans, rotates, etc. In SceneKit the equivalent is `allowsCameraControl`

- There's no `cameraMode` on the macOS ARView, probably because it only supports `nonAR` anyway.
- I tried adding a `PerspectiveCamera` hoping it would unlock interactivity, but no luck.

I guess I could just implement all the gestures myself, but that's a lot of work, and Apple seems to be using a standard way to interact with the scene with a mouse - and also a standard grid, which I'd love to use, too.

I'm using macOS 12 beta 1, but it shouldn't make a big difference since ARView requires macOS 10.15

Comment: https://rhonabwy.com/2022/03/15/realitykit-on-macos/

Answer (score 0):

Neither in macOS nor in iOS, RealityKit has a property similar to SceneKit's `.allowsCameraControl`. However, using this code as a [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516286/realitykit-as-a-framework-to-build-3d-nonar-apps/71516339#71516339), you can create your own camera control in RealityKit.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528947/how-can-i-move-a-modelentity-along-the-y-axis-using-gesture/71531053#71531053) can also be helpful for you.